# Codeigniter HMVC modules inside controller how to split three folder

Tags: codeigniter

My HMVC structure is:

1. `modules/login/controller/user.`
2. `modules/login/controller/admin.`
3. `modules/login/controller/manager.`

My doubt is if i try to access login i got 404 error .. how to i run?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: My structure i split login module to three sub folder.. If i run that sub folder i got error .My question is how to access that three folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access user.php from your path:1)modules/login/controller/user
 then your folder name should be "user". 
Or you could change your controller file name to login.php

example: modules/login/controllers/login.php 
     or : modules/user/controllers/user.php

**The key rule of HMVC is one module one controller.**

Note: Make sure that folder names are:

model**s**

view**s**

controller**s**

[image]

Comment: In structure : modules/login/user/user.php . And another file path is: modules/login/admin/admin.php. The login is parent folder for both.. How to i run both user and admin.

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of your file structure? So i can be more exact.

Comment: Firstly, ideal structure would be: modules/login/controllers/login.php. Secondly, there are 2 ways: Split the `admin()` functionality and `user()` functionality within  login.php file . OR Keep your structure as :  modules/user/controllers/user.php and modules/admin/controllers/admin.php . Since the filename(in your case user.php) must be same as controller parent foldername (here: modules/user/controllers/user.php) Here is a link that maybe helpful: [link](https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-59955.html)

Comment: I want to use sub folder inside login. inside login folder i have three folder user, admin, manager..each sub folder contains individual  controller.Login also contain controller.

Answer (score 0):

instead, you should have your structure like this

```
modules/user/controllers/user.php
modules/manager/controllers/manager.php
modules/admin/controllers/admin.php
```

and each of file you can add your login method

```
login()
```

You should try to have only one controller per module